# Error sql:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, datetime

I tried to enter the date of the current day with the following code:

```
string now = (DateTime.Today.Day + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year).ToString();
string tm = (DateTime.Today.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Today.Minute).ToString();
string sql2 = string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala2 (Nu_kabala,Ma_num,Sk,Seif_hacnasa,Seif_name,Date) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", n, Session["Ma_num"], lprice, lkod,des, now );
Dal.DoQuery(sql2);
```

when I run this code it shows me the error in the title :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

How do I solve it?

------------------edit

i changed it  to:`string now = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` and it works.

now i  have another problem, when i run the code below it shows me the error:Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
string now = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    string tm = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala1 (Nu_kabala,Ma_num,Date,Time,Total,Status,Name,User_n) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')", n, Session["Ma_num"], now, tm, lprice, "ddffs", Session["user"], "ddffs");
    Dal.DoQuery(sql);
    string sql2 = string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala2 (Nu_kabala,Ma_num,Sk,Seif_hacnasa,Seif_name,Date) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", n, Session["Ma_num"], lprice, lkod, des, now);
    Dal.DoQuery(sql2);
    string sql3 = string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala3 ((Nu_kabala,Msd,Ma_num,Kind_pay,Name_pay,Date_pay,Sk,Ms_sek,Snif,Bank,Date_klita,Seif) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')", n,"1", Session["Ma_num"],"13", "ddffds", now, lprice, this.card.Text, this.mm.Text, this.yy.Text, now, lkod);
    Dal.DoQuery(sql3);
```

Comment: Looks like your `tm` string is useless since you are not using them. What is your `sql2` looks like exactly when you debug your code?

Comment: i use 'now' at the end of the string sql2

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` //Whatever format...

or Use direct sql instead using CONVERT method. Syntax is

> in your case, use the 103 format for the date

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DateTime.Today.Day + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year,103)
```

> and 108 for the time

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTime.Today.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Today.Minute + ":00" ,108)
```

whould give format of hh:mm:ss

full reference from the following w3 link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 1):

The standard form for dates in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD.  I would suggest using this format.  Perhaps this will create the string in the right format:

```
string now = (DateTime.Today.Year + "-" + DateTime.Today.Month + "-" + DateTime.Today.Year).ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Change the date settings in your computer or lap. I hope you know how its is done !
If you don't...

1. choose your calendar from right bottom.
2. then choose `change date and time settings`
3. then choose `change date and time`
4. then choose `change calendar settings`
5. then in date formats> change short date as either `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy`. Choose which is right for your computer. For me it was `MM/dd/yyyy`.