# Error while taking date between two dates

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am trying to get date between two dates but i get error 
selection query is

```
DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text);
DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [LedId],[LedName] from [Ledger] where Date>='"+startdate+"' and Date<='"+enddate+"'", con);
```

error is
[image]

Comment: Show the values in the textboxes, which produces this error ! Also use command parameters

Comment: Use parameterized SQL - that may well be all you need. Never put values directly into SQL like this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but take a look at this question. Hope it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125076/sql-query-to-select-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: It probably thinks it's got the day and month the wrong way round.
Ideally, you'd be best converting to a date from this format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error sql:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722215/error-sqlthe-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted)

Comment: did you check that your start date was not greater than endate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, do not *hardcode*, use parametrized queries instead

```
   DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text);
   DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text);
   ...
   // Make sql readable
   string sql = 
     @"Select [LedId],
              [LedName] 
         from [Ledger] 
        where Date >= @prmStartDate and Date <= @prmEndDate";

   // wrap IDisposable (SqlCommand) into using
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate; 
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

     ... 
   }
```

Hardcoded queries are

- Prone to Sql injection
- Brittle (depends on, say, datetime formatting - the gap you fell into)
- Slow: there's performance decrease since RDBMS has to parse the query each time it executes it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle conversion is to let the provider handle that for you:

```
DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text);
DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [LedId],[LedName] from [Ledger] where Date >= @startDate and Date <= @endDate", con);


SqlParameter startParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate ",
                System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParameter endParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate",
                System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);

startParameter.Value = startdate;
endParameter.Value = enddate;

cmd.Parameters.Add(startParameter);
cmd.Parameters.Add(endParameter);
```

Don not concatenate strings when building up your SQL queries, this is prone to SQL injection and is considered a security issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your inputs, I would suggest you use [parameterized SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.110).aspx) in your C# or create a stored procedure to accept `DATETIME` parameters. You shouldn't use hardcoded SQL queries - in short: they are prone to attack and not optmized in SQL.

A really easy way to do this would be to use the [Dapper.NET object mapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

In SQL, you could do:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE return_led_for_dates
        @startdate      DATETIME,
        @enddate        DATETIME
    AS
    BEGIN
      SELECT
          [LedId],
          [LedName]
      FROM 
          [Ledger] 
      WHERE
          Date BETWEEN @Startdate AND @Enddate
   END
```

And with Dapper, your C# could then be:

```
  DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text);
  DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text);
  var LED = this.Connection.Query<LED>(
            "return_led_for_dates",
            new { 
               StartDate = startdate,
               EndDate = enddate 
             },
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

You would need an LED class too:

```
    public class LED
    {
         int LedId {get; set;},
         string LedName {get; set;}
    }
```

Finally, this assumes that there is no issue with your text field conversions, you should use `DateTime.TryParse`. You can then bullet proof your code, and ensure the field is corretly parsed. Like:

```
    DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text), out startDate) && DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text), out endDate))
    {
       // Your data code.
    }
```